# Using same validation type multiple times on the same field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to use the same validation type (but with different options based on a condition) for the same field multiple times, like in the example below:

```
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 1, :if => :some_condition1 }
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 20, :if => :some_condition2 }
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 10, :unless => :some_condition3 }
```

But such way will not work correctly, since only the last validation would apply.
Is there any other way to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 1 }, :if => :some_condition1
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 20 }, :if => :some_condition2
validates :something, :length => { :minimum => 10 }, :unless => :some_condition3
```

Take the conditions outside the length's options.

Also you can take a look at [Conditional Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
validate :length_of_something


def length_of_something
  length = self.something.length
  valid = case
  when some_condition1
    lengh >= 1
  when some_condition2
    length >= 2 && length <= 20
  when some_condition3
    length > 10
  end
  errors.add(:something, :invalid) unless valid
end
```